# GIT: How to sync existing remote branch with existing local dir

Tags: git, version-control

So, I have local dir, very simplified example:

```
repo/
  foo/
    bar.txt (newer version)
    somefile.txt
    ...
    anotherfile.txt
```

Also I have remote repository, like this

```
repo/
  foo/
    bar.txt (older version)
    importantfile.txt
```

This folders are never has been synced.

I want to sync files, that already existed on remote repo only (bar.txt & importantfile.txt in example above).
So, the problem is if I do

```
git init
git git remote add origin [url]
git fetch origin
git add .
```

then git add to commit all local files, but I want to track files that already existed on remote.

Already tried to find any solution on other threads, but unsuccessful.

Please, help. P.S. i'm a git newbie.

Comment: "*track files that already existed on remote*" `git fetch` does that automatically. What else do you need?

Comment: @phd after `git fetch` local folder `foo` are stay "untracked"

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are looking for `git add -u` (`git add --update`).

This will update the index (meaning those files which are already on the remote will get updated)

**important: backup both your local and remote repo because this will update the index**

And

- cd to a temporary folder
- do `git clone <your-remote-repp-url>`
- copy the .git directory from the newly created clone
- replace the .git directory in your local dir with the copied one
- then do `git add -u` from the local dir
- finally `git commit` and `git push`

Answer (score 0):

`git add .` tells git to add(stage) everything in the current folder.

That is not usually how git will be used. Most of the time one would actually select which changes should go into the next commit. `git add bar.txt` will only stage the single file.

You can also stage multiple files with `git add bar.txt importantfile.txt`

`git add -u .` will stage all files that have changed and are already tracked.

Edit: git does not actually care about syncing a folder. You can always delete everything and write the files new. In git a commit is always a snapshot of the complete files you staged, instead of a change set.

Edit2: sorry i didn't notice this earlier but your workflow still has master pointing to nowhere. This works on my end.

```
git init
git git remote add origin [url]
git fetch origin
git reset origin/master
git add -u
```

Comment: I have about 10k files on remote and rather more at local. It impossible to add each file manually

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. But with 10k files, I would guess you are not writing them by hand. As a rule of thump generated files are not good candidates to add to git. Git has its limits and there might be better solutions for your use case. Otherwise `git add -u .` will do what you asked for.

Comment: I already tried this one. But after `git add -u .` "foo" folder stays "untracked"

Comment: according to the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) -u should add all tracked files. Have you tried `git add -u` without the folder?

Comment: Sure. `... git fetch origin && git add -u ` , and still untracked.

Comment: just tried it. it does not matter if you add the folder both `git add -u` and `git add -u .` work. So let me guess your `master` does not point to anywhere. `git reset origin/master` sets master to the point where your remote is. Maybe then `git add -u` will work?

Comment: I just noticed that I forget checkout branch after `git init && fetch`. If `git checkout origin/master && git add -u` then files become tracked, but I loose all local changes. I also tried `git checkout -b update && git add -u` then `foo` folder is still untracked. What i did wrong?

Comment: After `git reset origin/master` I'll loose all local changes again, isn't it?

Comment: only `git reset` with the `--hard` flag should overwrite you working directory.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think you are already on the right track. Here is how I think it should work.

Recommendation: Make a backup before you try this!

You start in the directory where all your files are. It's a good idea to "clean" the directory (so there should be no files you are not interested in); but this is not 100% necessary.

Then:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "my files"
git remote add rmt <URL to remote repository>
git fetch rmt
git branch -r    // look at the remote branches
git merge -Xours --allow-unrelated-histories  rmt/master
```

Here a short explanation what this does.

- First three commands (up to including `git commit`): Put all your local files into your own local git repository
- next two commands (up to including `git fetch`): Tell git where your remote repository is and fetch the content; in this example I call it "rmt"; you might choose any name here. Just my recommendation: **DO NOT** name it "origin"; because this name is usually reserved for the repository you cloned your own local repository from. But this is **not** what you are doing here.
- `git branch -r` This is to get an idea what branches are available on the remote repository called "rmt". In the next line I just assume you are interested in the "master" branch on the remote repository
- `git merge` Now comes the magic :-)

The important part here are the options for `merge`:

- `-Xours` tells git to **not** overwrite any of your files with the files from the remote repository. So this makes sure your already existing files are untouched. From the description I am not 100% sure if this is what you want. If you leave out this option, then git will try to merge files, which have different content; but this might be problematic. (You have to read up on git merge strategies if you want something else here).
- `--allow-unrelated-histories` Here is something you have to understand: The way this is done here means, that **your** repository has currently absolutely **nothing** to do with the remote repository. To wrap your head around this: git stores snapshots of a directory. You created a snapshot of your directory (with the first three commands). There also is another snapshot of a directory on the remote repository, which you copied into your own repository with `git fetch`. Additionally to a snapshot, git stores history in the sense that it remembers which snapshot got generated out of which other snapshot(s); these are the "ancestors" of a snapshot. But **your** snapshot was an "initial" snapshot without any ancestors. So it has absolutely no correlation to any other snapshot from the remote repository. Of course the way you describe it, I guess that at some point you copied the remote repository, but at least git does not know about that. The result is, that git **usually** would **not** accept to merge these two snapshots, because in gits view these two snapshots are completely unrelated. With the option here, you tell git to simply ignore this unrelated history and just merge the two snapshots anyway.

you might then look at what you did with `git log`. You should see something like

```
commit ... (HEAD -> master)
Merge: ... ...
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Dec 5 02:08:55 2020 +0100

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'rmt/master'

commit ...
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Dec 5 02:03:24 2020 +0100

    my files
```

You might have a look at which files were added with `git show HEAD`.

You might check out the differences between your freshly generated snapshot and the remote branch by `git diff rmt/master..HEAD`. This shows what you have to change in "rmt/master" to get to your snapshot, after the merge.